# Why should we always derive from a base class in Qt?

Tags: qt

While we use Qt, we always derive a new class from the Qt Classes and make an instance of our new class. For example, in order to use the QMainWindow class, we derive a new class from the QMainWindow for example called MW and make an instance from the MW.

My question is why don't we make an instance from the base class, from QMainWindow in this situation?

Answer (score 3):

Huh, I've been using Qt for years and never even thought about this - good question.

I would say if you can use QMainWindow without subclassing it - go ahead. But I would think the usefulness of the base QMainWindow class itself would be fairly limited.

I usually have hundreds or thousands of lines of code in the subclass, doing things like creating menus, hooking up signals and slots, etc. I'm not sure where this code would logically exist if not in a subclass.

It's also possible that QMainWindow has pure virtuals, so you'd have to override it. But I don't know, never looked.

Hope that answers what I understand to be your question.

Comment: If it had pure virtuals, you had to implement them every time. I think you had noticed this if it were the case ;)

Comment: Yeah in order to do any custom painting or gobble up key/mouse events, you must subclass.  Sublcassing is also a bit like .net controls.  While you could have some non-widget code that puts together subclassed widgets to make a complex gui.  It's all what floats your boat.

Comment: @leemes: gah, I'm such an idiot! I can't believe they still let me post on here ;-0

Comment: I would add that with Qt you usually implement slots and it makes sense to implement them in the widget that receives and handle the related events. You could code the GUI initialization on a QMainWindow instance without subclassing, but it would get messy to implement its behaviour elsewhere than in a subclass.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to subclass QWidget / QMainWindow, but the QtCreator assistant for creating new projects and new UI files does so.

The reasons are simple:

1. It enforces cleaner code. You put **behavior** of this widget / window in one class, not outside the class. So every instance of your window has the same behavior. If you would simply instantiate a QWidget / QMainWindow and add behavior from outside (by connecting to signals of the widgets you need to create from outside), those instances could have different behaviors, which is clearly not what we understand by object oriented design.
2. The **child widgets** can be added as members. As you should know, adding members to a class can only happen if you subclass it. Not subclassing it would mean that you need to store those pointers in the code using the widget / main window, resulting in bad code. Note that you do not necessarily store pointers to child widgets, as they are put into the QObject tree and managed by Qt internally. But connecting to signals, reading values like text from QLineEdit and a lot more can only happen if you have the pointers to those widgets.
3. **Handling events** requires subclassing [*EDIT: It can also be achieved using event filters, see comments*], as those are implemented as virtual methods and not as signals. This also includes custom painting, which is done by reimplementing the virtual `paintEvent`. Handling events also includes reacting on mouse clicks (apart from clicks on subwidgets, which handle this themselves), mouse wheel rotations, key presses, minimizing and maximizing, and a lot more. The only "actions" on windows you can handle using a signal-slot connection is closing it and requesting the context menu (right click), if you enable it. So those two don't require subclassing necessarily.

Talking more generally in the context of good object oriented code, the rule when to create subclasses is clearly the following:

- If you have instances of *the same thing, behaving the same on the same inputs / attributes*, it **should be of the same type**.
- But as soon as you have instances you want to *behave differently, not only depending on different inputs / attributes*, it **should be another type (subclass)**.
- As soon as you need to *change* some (already defined) behavior of a class ("overwrite it") or add some members, it **necessarily has to be another type (subclass)**.

Comment: "Handling events REQUIRES subclassing". Not true, often the same can be achieved by registering an event listener.

Comment: "If you would simply instantiate a QWidget / QMainWindow and add behavior from outside [...] those instances could have different behaviors, which is clearly not what we understand by object oriented design." Connecting an object with other objects is not changing its behavior, it's composition. The "composition over inheritance" rule suggests that one shouldn't subclass where the same can be achieved via configuration and composition.

Comment: s/event listener/event filter/, obviously.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld I find it very dirty if you want to have a window behaving the same but instantiated from two points in code, and NOT subclass QWidget to achieve this but rather add the same child widgets from outside at both points in code. You can avoid code duplication by creating a "makeMeWindowX()" method, creating this composite (the ui generated .h files do exactly this), but this is again not very clean. Clean code would be if you have a WindowX and just instantiate it where you need it.

Comment: The same applies for event handling: If you want two windows to handle events in the same way, they should NOT being added event filters from outside, but DEFINE its own event handling routine by subclassing from QWidget and overwriting the event function. *This* is object oriented design, where the *class* defines how to behave, not the client code.

Answer (score 0):

Saying that one should "always" subclass sounds dangerous. I'd rather follow "Composite when you can, inherit when you have to".

A QWidget is useless and empty in itself other than in a few cases where it can act as container, and its meant to be specialized to actually do something.

QMainWindow can be perfectly used without subclassing by adding a central widget, menu bar etc. from outside. As the QAction's from toolbar buttons, menu entries etc. need to get hooked up somewhere, the mainwindow often contains the slots acting on those actions, which suggests subclassing. Having a central place connecting the different pieces, bringing up dialogs etc. is somewhat natural and okay IMO, if it doesn't get out of hand. I.e. if the main window contains much more logic than forwarding action triggers and simply bringing up dialogs, one should consider to move that logic out of the mainwindow.

There are many other widgets though which are not designed for subclassing and there's no point in subclassing them by default, without good reason.
There's rarely a point in subclassing QLineEdit, QPushButton (subclass QAbstractButton if you need a special button), QCheckBox etc., as they don't offer widget-specific virtual methods that can be reimplemented to change behavior. Unless you reimplement a virtual method, composition is almost always the better way to achieve a goal.
Yes, there are case where reimplementing fooEvent() might be more straight-forward then registering an event filter. In those cases do it, but creating a "MyLinedit" whenever you need a QLineEdit is nonsensical and bad practice to me.

Comment: -1 Ouch. When we want a custom line edit (let's say a line edit having a "restore to default" button to its right) at a lot points in our code, we **SHOULD** subclass QLineEdit, of course! Composing it again and again in the same way at different points in code would clearly be a *very bad design* and **not** object oriented. The same applies for whole QWidgets with their contents. OP didn't ask if we can do it without inheritance, but asked why we inherit. And this is exactly why we do. This is why Qt suggests it.

Comment: I don't say that you shouldn't subclass QLineEdit if necessary. I just say that you should think twice before you do it. Also, composition doesn't imply "doing it over and over again". You can always have a class that holds the composition (works better with non-widget code than with widgets, admittedly), or have a free function assemble something.

Comment: Hmm... I think it is a question about opinion and code style, rather than what is possible technically. I just don't like your statement "Composite when you can, inherit when you have to". In my optinion it should be "Composite when you compose, inherit when you define behavior".